# How to start another apps when click a button?

Tags: blackberry, parameter-passing, uiapplication

I want to start another apps when I click this button.

```
sharebtn = new Custom_ButtonField(share, shareactive, shareactive) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                //I want to start another apps (Strawberry)
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(sharebtn);
```

Here is the Strawberry Apps

```
public class StrawBerry extends UiApplication implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String url) {
    new StrawBerry(url).enterEventDispatcher();
}
}
```

I want to pass `String url` to Strawberry apps. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are going to ship Strawberry app together with yours? Why don't use BB FB SDK in your app directly?

Comment: @EugenMartynov, I wish I could do that, how to achieve it?

Comment: Download FB SDK library, include to your project, use samples how to post on FB wall from it

Comment: The strawberry sample not fb sdk?

Comment: How to share a link to facebook with this fb sdk? can provide me a sample? thanks @EugenMartynov

Comment: Strawberry is sample app from BB FB SDK authors. I think it's even same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your main method won't be never called by system. The right signature:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments){}
```

Take a look on this article to launch another app with parameters : [How To - Launch a third-party application from another third-party application](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/How_To_-_Launch_a_third-party_application_from_another_third-party_application.html?nodeid=1094023&vernum=0)

To post on FB page. You need something like:

```
private final String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
private final String APPLICATION_ID = "your id";
private final String APPLICATION_SECRET = "your secret";
private Facebook fb;
private User user;
...
fb = Facebook.getInstance(new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, Facebook.Permissions.PUBLISH_STREAM));
user = fb.getUser(pUserId);
user.publishPost(messageEditField.getText(), linkEditField.getText(), pictureEditField.getText(), nameEditField.getText(), captionEditField.getText(), descriptionEditField.getText(), sourceEditField.getText());
```